# How to concatenate two infinite streams in fish shell?

Tags: shell, fish

In Fish shell, how can I group commands such that e.g. all should be piped to the same next command?

For example, in `bash`

```sh
# With "normal" commands
(cat file1; cat file2) | xargs -I% echo 'this is a line: %'

# Or with commands that might not end, to intertwine the output of both
(tail -f infinite-log1 & tail -f infinite-log2) | xargs -I% echo 'this is a line: %'
```

At first I thought I could solve it with `cat` and `psub`, but that doesn't work because either one of those is not made for infinite streams.

```
# This won't work
cat (infinite-stream-1 | psub) (infinite-stream-2 | psub) | xargs -I% echo 'this is a line: %'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `begin` and `end` instead of the parentheses. E.g.

```
begin; tail -f infinite-log1 & tail -f infinite-log2; end | xargs -I% echo 'this is a line: %'
```

Note that fish's backgrounding capabilities are limited, it currently can't background functions.